# React Webpack.config.js issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Being fairly new to the world of react, I'm trying to create a successfully webpack.config.js for my react solution. My webpack.config.js contains the following code:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'Caching',
          template: './index.html'
        })
      ],    
    output: {
        filename: 'main.[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].[hash].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        clean: true,
        publicPath: "" 
    },
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
         runtimeChunk: 'single',
         splitChunks: {
           cacheGroups: {
             vendor: {
               test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
               name: 'vendors',
               chunks: 'all',
             },
           },
         },
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader' },
                    { 
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                            },                                                      
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                     }
                  ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=img/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

However, when I execute npm run build the following files are created.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ6Rc.png)

And the webpack.plugin interjects this line into my entry point
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpViS.png)

Which is obvious the wrong name, producing a 404 error message. I have read a number of articles about [creating Webpack.config.js](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)  but I'm unable to resolve my issue for removing the 404 error and getting the correct filename interjected into my entry point

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: For me, it also didn't put the correct outputs, so I added a `inject: false` in Html plugin options and put it manually (but my script names had no hashes, it is harder for you).